# Why was my comment correcting the accusations against Bill Clinton deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-comments

[This answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/13433/8651) claims that one of the reasons "Hillary Clinton seems untrustworthy to Americans" is

> - attacking the women accusing her husband of adultery

When I pointed out that [the accusations were actually of rape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Clinton_sexual_misconduct_allegations#Juanita_Broaddrick), the comment chain was swiftly deleted.

I'd like to know why this was. It may be a distasteful subject but it was a legitimate response to the answer given.

Comment: Instead of a comment, simply propose an edit (and explain in edit description why your edit makes the asnwer improved). If you don't have enough rep, your edit will have to be reviewed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comments are considered disposable, and aren't suitable for extended discussions. Posting *one* comment voicing your disagreement with an answer in *a constructive manner* is fine, but anything other than and you might find the whole discussion purged.

This is what happened here. Your comment was flagged, which brought the discussion between you and the OP to my attention. I felt the discussion had taken a rather nonconstructive turn, so I deleted the whole thing.

---

Further reading:

- [Commenting guidelines](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)
- [LOTS of comments being deleted](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/289/101)

Comment: People are invited to read our commenting guidelines when they first earn the privilege to comment everywhere @grovkin. If they choose to ignore those guidelines, their comments will probably be removed. I don't see how that's censorship.

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember your comment nor the ensuing discussion.  But if you think that the rape allegations should be mentioned, I'd suggest writing your own answer.  Note that it should concentrate more on how Hillary Clinton responded than how Bill Clinton did.  Unless of course you are arguing that she is perceived as untrustworthy because of things that he did.

This is especially so since that particular answer, to my mind, is quite biased in favor of Hillary.  That author may well be one of those who rejects the thesis that Bill raped or sexually assaulted women.  The accusations and the criticism of Hillary as an enabler are purely right wing fantasies in that view.

Rather than arguing in comments, it is often better to post a well-cited answer of your own.  Let people make up their own minds.

Note that I avoided discussing the allegations against Bill in my answer.  This was both because much of what's involved reflects more on Bill than on Hillary and because she hasn't actually said much.  So even though I haven't found her behavior relative to women who accused Bill admirable, I haven't necessarily found many examples of her being untrustworthy in that area.

Basically I think that there are some challenges there.  But if you disagree, you are welcome to write your own answer.  Expect criticism though.  This is a particularly contentious area of an already contentious subject.